# Proper AWS RDS Storage Sizes/Reallocation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

For my RDS, I have a reserved db.r3.large instance. A couple of questions:

- Do I need to spawn a db.r3.large instance to work with the reserved one, or can I use a smaller instance (i.e. db.t2.large)?
- When it asks for the size of Allocated Storage, it says the minimum must be 5GB and the max is 6144GB. Does the price of the instance vary with the size you enter in this field? For example, is 5GB $0.07 and 1000GB is $0.75?

Thank you in advance for the help and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you reserved a db.r3.large instance, then you have to create a db.r3.large instance to take advantage of the reservation.
- Storage is not included in the price of the instance. Look at the "Storage and IO" costs section on [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/).